# change selected value in dropdown based on url using jquery

Tags: jquery, iphone

Here is what i am trying to do:

```
<select id="dynamic_select">
<option value="http://blog.mysite.com/">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="http://fr.blog.mysite.com/">France</option>
<option value="http://de.blog.mysite.com/">Deutschland</option>
<option value="http://it.blog.mysite.com/">Italia</option>
<option value="http://jp.blog.mysite.com/">日本</option>
<option value="http://es.blog.mysite.com/">España</option>
</select>
```

First Script

```
jQuery(function(){
  // bind change event to select
  jQuery('#dynamic_select').bind('change', function () {
      var url = jQuery(this).val(); // get selected value
      if (url) { // require a URL
          window.location = url; // redirect
      }
      return false;
  });
});
```

Another Script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 if(window.location.href.indexOf("fr") != -1) {
jQuery("#dynamic_select option[value='2']").attr('selected', 'selected');
}
});
```

This is a language selector which will be displayed on iphone (using WPtouchPro), the first part i.e. change of url based on selection is working perfect.. but i want to change the option selected in the drop down list with the value equal to the url of the page..
Also how to write those Japanese letter so that they display properly on all browsers..
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use UTF-8 charset for Japanese characters:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

by using `data` attribute you can try this:

```
<select id="dynamic_select">
<option data-c="uk" value="http://blog.mysite.com/">United Kingdom</option>
<option data-c="fr" value="http://fr.blog.mysite.com/">France</option>
<option data-c="de" value="http://de.blog.mysite.com/">Deutschland</option>
<option data-c="it" value="http://it.blog.mysite.com/">Italia</option>
<option data-c="jp" value="http://jp.blog.mysite.com/">日本</option>
<option data-c="es" value="http://es.blog.mysite.com/">España</option>
</select>
```

supposing `window.location.href.slice(7, 9)` equals to `de`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      lt = "de";
    $("#dynamic_select option").each(function(){
       if ($(this).data("c") == lt ) $(this).prop("selected", true);
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qj8x8/1/

Comment: this didn't work either... also tried .attr("selected", "selected")

Comment: it works if i use    jQuery("#dynamic_select option[value^='fr']").prop("selected", true);

Comment: @Lucky Soni yes but it is not dynamic, i have coded another script i will modify ma answer.

Comment: Thanks.. really appreciate all your help.. Also if i remove the 'http' from the option values then the 1st part doesn't work (url redirection)

Comment: @ Lucky Soni in updated answer there is no need to modify `url`s